# LINQ to return true if collection contains element satisfying predicate

Tags: linq, nullable

```
public enum Status
{
  Unspecified = 0,
  Good = 1,
  Broken = 2
}

IEnumerable<Status> Statuses;
```

If `Statuses` is `null` or `empty` I want to return `false`.

If `Statuses` contains one or more `Broken` I want to return `true`.

```
public bool AnyBroken => (Statuses != null) && Statuses.Count(s => s == Status.Broken) > 0;
```

I want to simplify the syntax. I think I can use `?` or `??` but I'm not quite seeing how.

Answer (score 1):

You could use [Enumerable.Any](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.any?view=netframework-4.8). For example

```
public bool AnyBroken => Statuses?.Any(x=>x == Status.Broken)==true;
```

Comment: But what if `Statuses` is `null` ?

Comment: "Statuses?" would return null, which is not equal to "true". Hence AnyBroken would get evaluated to false.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this way, Link for live demo [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/3JAO49)

Note that: [You has just use `Null-conditional operators` of C# 6 Feature or higher version](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/whats-new/csharp-6#null-conditional-operators)

```
using System;
using System.Linq;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        var listContainBroken = new [] { Status.Broken,  Status.Unspecified }; 
        var listDoesNotContainBroken = new [] { Status.Unspecified }; 

        Console.WriteLine("List Contain Broken: " + listContainBroken?.Any(s => s == Status.Broken));
        Console.WriteLine("List Does not Contain Broken: " + listDoesNotContainBroken?.Any(s => s == Status.Broken));
    }

    public enum Status
    {
      Unspecified = 0,
      Good = 1,
      Broken = 2
    }
}
```